# Append data to table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to append `json` data in table. Json data format `{"FirstName":"Cho"
,"LastName":"Chee","Company":"solution"}`. This code did not show data in table as expected.

JQuery Code:

```
var uri = 'api/Employee/GetData';
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON(uri)
    .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#tbdata"));
        });
    });
});

function formatItem(item) {
return item.FirstName + '  ' + item.LastName + ' ' + item.Company;
}
```

HTML table :

```
<table class="table-bordered table-striped table table-hover" id="tbdata">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: So you are trying to append `li` elements to a `table`?!...

Comment: trying to append it to `td`, but I have no idea in how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at below code snippet. I am assuming you will get array of data from your server.

```js
function formatItem(item) {
return '<td>'+item.FirstName + '</td> <td> ' + item.LastName + ' </td><td>' + item.Company+'</td>';
}

var data = [
{"FirstName":"Cho","LastName":"Chee","Company":"solution"},
{"FirstName":"Cho1","LastName":"Chee1","Company":"solution1"},
{"FirstName":"Cho2","LastName":"Chee2","Company":"solution2"},
];

$.each(data, function (key, item) {

            $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#tbdata"));
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-bordered table-striped table table-hover" id="tbdata">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: this code works well, but it only display the first record. I need to click ok button to display records one by one..How to make all records append once!

Comment: thanks @Manea. I forgot to remove that alert... `:)`!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to add are whole table rows with table data cells for each item property. Additionally you want to add this to the table body not to the table as a whole. I would do it like this:

HTML:

```
<table class="table-bordered table-striped table table-hover">
<thead>  
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbdata">
<!-- data will go here -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON(uri)
    .done(function (data) {
        var html = "";
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            html += formatItem(item); 
        });
        $("#tbdata").append(html);
    });
});
function formatItem(item) {
    return '<tr><td>' item.FirstName + '</td><td>' + item.LastName + '</td><td>' + item.Company + '</td></tr>';
}
```